# How many distances are required to calculate all distances among $n$ points in the Euclidean plane?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I want to know all the pairwise distances between points $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$ in the Euclidean plane (or equivalently, I want to reconstruct the set of points up to congruence). Let's say I have an oracle that will tell me distances of my choice (e.g. I can ask for $P_1P_4$). What is the minimum number of distances I can request that will always suffice?

For instance, with 3 points, I need all 3 distances. With 4 points, I need all 6 distances, though 5 distances are *almost* enough: with 5 distances, there are only two possible configurations (essentially two triangles joined at a hinge). With $n$ points, $3n-6$ distances definitely suffice (as each new point can be triangulated using its distances to 3 existing points). However, $2n-3$ distances are enough to limit the possible configurations to a finite number, which makes me wonder if we really need $n-3$ more distances just to select among these configurations.

(Apologies if this has been asked before; it seems like it should be easily Googleable, but I couldn't come up with the right search terms.)

Comment: This 2022 paper addresses the $1$-dimensional version of your question: Benjamini, Itai, and Elad Tzalik. "Determining a Points Configuration on the Line from a Subset of the Pairwise Distances." arXiv:2208.13855 (2022). Roughly: need $n^{3/2}$ distances to determine all distances.

Comment: Another reference, not recent but cited by 130 later papers: Skiena, Steven S., Warren D. Smith, and Paul Lemke. "Reconstructing sets from interpoint distances." In *Proceedings 6th Symposium on Computational Geometry,* pp. 332-339. 1990.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to choose set of measurements in advance, then you have to make all measurements.
Indeed, suppose you did not measure distance $|x_i-x_j|$, then assuming that all other points lie on one line $\ell$, one can get another configurations by reflecting $x_i$ across $\ell$.

One the other hand, if you assume that the set is in general position, then $2{\cdot}n-2$ should be sufficient --- it is trianglulation of polygon + one extra diagonal. So it remains to decide $2{\cdot}n-2$ or $2{\cdot}n-3$.

Comment: Ah, excellent point in your first paragraph. If we do assume the set is in general position, why is $2n-2$ enough? I see that triangulation suffices if the points are in convex position, but I don't see why one extra diagonal deals with the nonconvex case.

Comment: @tuna Once you fix a triangulation, the remaining diagonal may take only finite number of values. You may choose it so that generically this diagonal changes if you change orientation of any set of triangles.

Comment: [Laman graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laman_graph) have $2n-3$ edges, so doesn't this imply that the answer is $2n-3$ in the generic case? As for the non-generic case, what if the oracle can be queried adaptively (i.e., you can choose your next query based on your knowledge of the results of previous queries)?

Comment: @TimothyChow Local rigidity, does not imply uniqueness of configuration. If after removing two vertices, your graph becomes disconnected, then there are at least two configurations. Many Laman graphs have such pairs, but some (for example, $K_{3,3}$) do not. Still I do not see a proof that these graphs are good.